# Dropbox returning no results. php

Tags: php, html, sql

Ive used this code in other projects I've made, for some reason now it is not working. To me it should work but I'm hoping someone will see the mistake I'm missing

```
//Actual Function
function get_data(){
   $mealData = mysql_query("SELECT `MealID`, `MealOption` FROM `menu` ");
   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mealData)){
       echo '<option value="'. $row['`MealOption`'] . '">'.$row['`MealOption`'].'</option>';
   }

//   HTML
<select name="Meal">
<?php  get_data() ?>
</select><br>

// Including
<?php
    include_once '@add_customer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function get_data(){
   $mealData = mysql_query("SELECT `MealID`, `MealOption` FROM `menu` ");
   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mealData)){
         $mealOption = $row['MealOption'];
          echo "<option value='$mealOption'>$mealOption</option>";
      }
<select name="Meal">
<?php  get_data() ?>
</select><br>


 // Including
<?php
include_once 'add_customer.php';
?>
```

Your backticks were misplaced.
I always prefer to assign the `MySQL`  output of to a variable first and then simply use it inside double quotes, it's easier to read.

---

If you're not sure where the error is, add the following code at the top of your php script, this way you'll be able to detect any errors your script may have, remove it when in production mode.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: still returning an empty result :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use backtick ` in array key name

Change

```
echo '<option value="'. $row['`MealOption`'] . '">'.$row['`MealOption`'].'</option>';
```

to

```
echo '<option value="'. $row['MealOption'] . '">'.$row['MealOption'].'</option>';
```

---

and just use `include_once 'add_customer.php';` not `include_once '@add_customer.php';`